# Changes in GNU C++ stdlib std::variant implementation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang, c++17

I have the following example with std::variant usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

class Cat {
public:
    const std::string& getSound() const { return sound; };

private:
    std::string sound = "Meow.";
};

class Dog {
public:
    const std::string& getSound() const { return sound; };

private:
    std::string sound = "Bark.";
};

class House {
public:
    void resetAnimal(const auto&& animal) { v = std::move(animal); }
    const auto& getAnimal() const {
        return std::visit([](const auto& animal) -> decltype(animal)&
                          { return animal; }, v);
    }

private:
    std::variant<Cat, Dog> v;
};

int main() {
    House house;
    house.resetAnimal(Cat());

    std::cout << house.getAnimal().getSound() << std::endl;

    house.resetAnimal(Dog());

    std::cout << house.getAnimal().getSound() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The funny thing with it is that it compiles with compillers from g++-8 to g++-10. (using flags `-std=c++17` and `-fpermissive`) and fails while using g++-11. If it compiles, it works as expected - prints 'Meow.' and 'Bark.' on separate lines. The error massage looks like this (g++-11):

```
In file included from <source>:3:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/variant: In instantiation of 'constexpr decltype(auto) std::visit(_Visitor&&, _Variants&& ...) [with _Visitor = House::getAnimal() const::<lambda(const auto:23&)>; _Variants = {const std::variant<Cat, Dog>&}]':
<source>:25:26:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/variant:1758:29: error: static assertion failed: std::visit requires the visitor to have the same return type for all alternatives of a variant
 1758 |               static_assert(__visit_rettypes_match,
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/variant:1758:29: note: '__visit_rettypes_match' evaluates to false
<source>: In member function 'const auto& House::getAnimal() const':
<source>:26:48: error: forming reference to void
   26 |                           { return animal; }, v);
      |                                                ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

While compilling using MSVC I get message with a pretty close meaning.
My questions are:

- Is it possible to compile the example code using `g++-11`? If the answer is 'Yes.', then how?
- Why adding `-fpermissive` makes g++ compiller work in this situation?
- Is it possible to compile the example code using MSVC?
- Is it possible to compile using clang? (I tried.)

P.S. I know about inheritance and templates. I just have an interest, is it possible to do the way I do in the example.

Comment: What is `decltype(std::declval<House>().getAnimal())` supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc-8 is broken in allowing this, and produces broken code when you try to use it.

Putting aside the official definition of `std::visit()` and `std::variant<>` for a second, this intuitively *has* to be the case from a pure language standpoint.

To demonstrate this, let's ask ourselves the question: "What is the return type of `getAnimal()`?". This has to be determined at compilation time after all.

A function that returns `auto` has its return type entirely determined by its arguments. In this case, there is only the `House` `this`, and nothing else. So the current state of the variant *cannot* influence the returned type. What can it possibly be? Maybe some kind of inferred dependant `variant<>`? But then you wouldn't be able to call `getSound()` on it directly, so that can't be it.

Let's stop wondering, and just check it ourselves with `typeid()`:

```
using T = decltype(std::declval<House>().getAnimal());
std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";

// ...
result:
  3Cat
```

Looks like we only ever get cats out of this function! We can confirm that by changing your code a bit:

```
class Cat {
public:
    const std::string& getSound() const { 
      std::cout << "I am cat\n"; 
      return sound; 
    };

private:
    std::string sound = "Meow.";
};

class Dog {
public:
    const std::string& getSound() const { 
      std::cout << "I am dog\n"; 
      return sound; 
    };

private:
    std::string sound = "Bark.";
};

//...
result:
  I am cat
  Meow.
  I am cat    <--------- !!!!!!
  Bark.
```

That fact that it "works" in your example is a minor miracle caused by `Cat` and `Dog` happening to have equivalent memory layouts.

It's still Undefined Behavior, even if it "works".

Answer (score 2):

As for [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), the visitor is a Callable returning the same type R with any combination of types from variants. Your visitor returns different types. GCC's libstdc++ did not check this rule until GCC11. This was updated later, the diagnostics was added:
[libstdc++: Fix visitor return type diagnostics [PR97449]](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/1f65bf2aa65609c0cd88af1b83191d37d6729f46).

Comment: It is funny that the issue was not fixed in `g++` for so long.